# Finding out when both JSON requests have completed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have the following code:

```
function render(url1, url2, message) {
    utility.messageBoxOpen(message);

    $.getJSON(url1, function (items) {
        // Do something

        utility.messageBoxClose();
    });

    $.getJSON(url2, function (items) {
        // Do something
    });
}
```

When the function is executed a modal window appears to inform the user something is loading. Initially I only had one $getJSON request so when the request was done the modal window closed as per the code above.

I am looking to add another $getJSON request but want to close the modal window only when both $getJSON requests have completed.

What is the best way of achieving this?

Comment: can you be a little more specific than "when both $getJSON requests have completed"? Do you mean when both are simply finished? Do you mean when both have returned successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [$.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

All jQuery ajax requests (including shortcuts like getJSON) return deferred objects which can be used to control other actions.

```
var dfd1 = $.getJSON(url1, function (items) {
    // Do something    
});

var dfd1 =  $.getJSON(url2, function (items) {
    // Do something
});

$.when(dfd1, dfd2).then(function(){
    //both succeeded
    utility.messageBoxClose();
},function(){
    //one or more of them failed
});
```

If you don't care whether the getJSONs come back successfully or not and instead only care that they are done you can instead:

```
$.when(dfd1, dfd2).done( utility.messageBoxClose );
```

Answer (score 2):

A variable

```
function render(url1, url2, message) {
utility.messageBoxOpen(message);
var isOneDone = false;
$.getJSON(url1, function (items) {
    // Do something
    if(!isOneDone)
        isOneDone = true;
    else
        utility.messageBoxClose();
});

$.getJSON(url2, function (items) {
    // Do something

    if(!isOneDone)
        isOneDone = true;
    else
        utility.messageBoxClose();
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `getJSON()` call to one using `$.ajax` which accomplishes the same thing but gives you more flexibility:

```
$.ajax({
  url: http://whatever,
  dataType: 'json',
  async: false,
  data: {data},
  success: function(data) {
    // do the thing
  }
});
```

Note the `async:false` part - this makes the code execution pause until the request is completed. So you could simply make your two calls this way, and close the dialog after the second call is completed.

Comment: Don't use `async:false`. It's almost always the wrong approach.

Comment: I disagree, especially if the call is known to be very low latency. While there are ways to 'fake' synchronicity, most I've seen are too convoluted or fragile. It's the 80/20 rule here, in most cases it won't matter that you're making a synchronous call anyway. If it does then you probably have bigger issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
function render(url1, url2, message) {
    utility.messageBoxOpen(message);
    $.when($.getJSON(url1, function (items) {
        // Do something
        utility.messageBoxClose();
    }), $.getJSON(url2, function (items) {
        // Do something
    })).then(function () {
        //Both complete
    });
}
```

[jQuery.when](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)